# Magento2 email issue on guest checkout

Tags: magento2, order-email, guest-checkout

I'm making a payment method where the customer is redirected to an external cash page and then back to the site once the payment is completed. With a logged in user everything works correctly. When I try to checkout as a guest I find the following screen:
[image]

The function that creates the url for redirection is as follows:

```
public function getUrlXPay() {

    /* $_quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
      $_quote->collectTotals();
      $_quote->reserveOrderId(); */ //->save();

    $orderIncrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

    /*
     * Se lingua pagina di cassa AUTOMATICA rilevo locale sito altrimenti metto quella scelta dal Merchant in configurazione
     */
    if ($this->getConfigData('language') == "AUTO") {
        /*
         * Converto local in codice pagina di cassa X-Pay, di default lascio INGLESE
         */
        $locale = $this->getLocaleCode();
        $aLang = array('it_IT' => 'ITA', 'it_CH' => 'ITA',
            'en_AU' => 'ENG', 'en_CA' => 'ENG', 'en_IE' => 'ENG', 'en_NZ' => 'ENG', 'en_GB' => 'ENG', 'en_US' => 'ENG',
            'es_AR' => 'SPA', 'es_CL' => 'SPA', 'es_CO' => 'SPA', 'es_CR' => 'SPA', 'es_MX' => 'SPA', 'es_PA' => 'SPA', 'es_PE' => 'SPA', 'es_ES' => 'SPA', 'es_VE' => 'SPA',
            'fr_CA' => 'FRA', 'fr_FR' => 'FRA',
            'de_AT' => 'GER', 'de_DE' => 'GER', 'de_CH' => 'GER',
            'ja_JP' => 'JPN');
        if (isset($aLang[$locale])) {
            $languageId = $aLang[$locale];
        } else {
            $languageId = 'ENG';
        }
    } else {
        $languageId = $this->getConfigData('language');
    }

    /*
     * Prendo Moneta corrente di magento e imposto EUR per CartaSì (valore fisso)
     */
    //$currencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $currencyCode = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
    $divisa = 'EUR';

    $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId();

    /*
     * Setto Importo, Url, Alias e String per Calcolo MAC in base al settaggio del modulo tra produzione e test
     */
    $importo = $order->getGrandTotal();
    if ($currencyCode != $divisa) {
        throw new Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException('Importo non in euro.');
        //$importo = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($importo, $currencyCode, $divisa);
    }

    $importo = strtr(round($importo * 100), array('.' => '', ',' => ''));
    if ($this->getConfigData('testmode') == 1) {
        /*
         * Dati di configurazione per effettuare i test
         */
        $alias = $this->getConfigData('alias_test');
        $stringaSegreta = $this->getConfigData('mac_test');
        $url = 'https://int-ecommerce.cartasi.it/ecomm/ecomm/DispatcherServlet';
    } else {
        /*
         * Se moneta diversa, converto in EUR prima di continuare
         */
        $alias = $this->getConfigData('alias');
        $stringaSegreta = $this->getConfigData('mac');
        $url = 'https://ecommerce.cartasi.it/ecomm/ecomm/DispatcherServlet';
    }

    /*
     * Prendo l'id della Sessione per il ritorno sul sito e lo uso anche per calcolare il Codice univoco della Transazione
     */
    /* $session_id = $_quote->getReservedOrderId();
      $codTrans = substr($quoteId . '-' . time(), 0, 30); */
    $session_id = $orderIncrementId;
    $codTrans = substr($orderIncrementId . '-' . time(), 0, 30);


    $sUrl = $url . '?';
    $sUrl .= 'alias=' . trim($alias);
    $sUrl .= '&codTrans=' . trim($codTrans);
    $sUrl .= '&importo=' . trim($importo);
    $sUrl .= '&divisa=' . trim($divisa);
    $sUrl .= '&languageId=' . trim($languageId);
    $sUrl .= '&session_id=' . trim($session_id);
    $sUrl .= '&urlpost=' . trim(urlencode($this->urlBuilder->getUrl('cartasixpay/payment/notificas2s', array('_secure' => true))));
    $sUrl .= '&url=' . trim(urlencode($this->urlBuilder->getUrl('cartasixpay/payment/conferma', array('_secure' => true)))); //'checkout/onepage/success'
    $sUrl .= '&url_back=' . trim(urlencode($this->urlBuilder->getUrl('cartasixpay/payment/annullo', array('_secure' => true))));
    $sUrl .= '&mail=' . trim($order->getCustomerEmail());
    $sUrl .= '&mac=' . sha1('codTrans=' . trim($codTrans) . 'divisa=' . trim($divisa) . 'importo=' . trim($importo) . $stringaSegreta);
    $sUrl .= '&descrizione=Ordine: ' . $orderIncrementId;
    $sUrl .= '&Note1=magento';
    $sUrl .= '&Note2=2.x';

    return $sUrl;
}
```

I also tried to comment on the line in which I get the email to be inserted in the url but the problem persists. Can someone help me?
I'm using Magento 2.1.3 for test.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get email of guest

```
$order->getCustomerEmail()
```

May be you have to use

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()
```

Saying based on this line of magento

```
->getBillingAddress()->setEmail($email)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to follow your instructions but the problem persists. I do not even know if it's the fault of my form, because the function that returns the email, even if it does not go back I will not throw exceptions. The problem may be that the server is not enabled to send mail? In system.log i find main.ERROR: Unable to send mail.

Comment: Than Please try simple mail sending script of php.

Comment: Script to send email using simple php :


$to      = 'xx@x.com';
$subject = 'the subject from mail';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: abc@abc.com' . "\r\n";

$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail($to,"My subject",$msg);

if($mail = 1){
 echo "send";
}
else{
 echo "Something Wrong"; 
}

Comment: I confirm that sending mail from php is disabled on the server for security issues. I read that you can not use a smtp with native magento2, I have to install a plugin. However, I do not understand how it can affect the plugin, even because with the registered user it works.

Comment: So you want to say that , mails are working for orders, register customers (e.g like forgot password), any custom module emails etc...
Are therse all emails working?

Comment: No, no mail is actually, but in the development of the plugin is not a fundamental thing.